# does URL Rewriting works with javascript window.open(url)?

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting

does URL Rewriting works with javascript window.open(url) ?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a .htaccess rewrite than YES it does work, as window.open(url) just opens a URL as a browser popup window.

Comment: Thanks Kau-Boy but i m doing it with rewrite.properties file.

Comment: I don't know that rewrite technique, but have you just tried it out? As it is a server side rewrite which is not visible to the client (and the browsers JavaScript calls) it should work anyways.